# How do I grep the text after two special characters?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to grep the data after  `>` & `|`. I used this command:

```
grep -o '  |.*$'| cut -c5-
```

But it just give the data after `|`:

```
                                                              > Aminobenzoate
Asthma                                                        | Atrazine
Autoimmune thyroid disease                                    | Bacterial
B cell receptor signaling pathway                             | Benzoate
Bile secretion                                                | beta-Lactam
                                                              > Biosynthesis
Caffeine metabolism                                           | Caprolactam
Calcium signaling pathway                                     | Carbapenem
```

#### Desired output:

```
Aminobenzoate
Atrazine
Bacterial
Benzoate
beta-Lactam
Biosynthesis
Caprolactam
Carbapenem
```

Comment: If this is the result of a `diff` command then you might want to look at suppressing the LHS altogether e.g. `diff --old-line-format=`

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using `sed` for that:

```
sed 's/.*[|>] *//'
```

This works for your example, but you may need to adapt it, depending on what to do with lines without any `|` or `>`. If those should get removed completely, use

```
sed -n 's/.*[|>] *//p'
```

This means don't output by default (option `-n`), but print a line (`p`), if the `s` command could perform a replacement.

Comment: i used this query (sed 's/.*[|>] *//') and i got my answer .

Answer (score 5):

`awk` can be used as well.  You can use multiple field separators using `-F` with `awk` to get both the `>` and `|`.  Also can use the `sub` option to clear first leading space that appear before the text when it prints the matching columns:

```
 awk -F'[>|]' '{sub(/^\ /, "",$2); print $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: You could roll the whitespace into the field separator, and avoid the `sub` e.g. `awk -F'[<|>] *' '{print $2}'`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you!  That is good to know.  I was actually trying to figure that one out.  When I tried it for some reason it pulled all the opposite lines.  =)

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk -F'[>|]' '{print$2}' input.txt | awk -F' ' '{print$1}'
```

OR

Suggested by [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914364/how-to-grep-two-special-characters-using-linux/914367#comment1440191_914367)

```
awk -F'[>|]' '{print substr($2,2)}' input.txt
```

Comment: This is a useless use of `cat`.

Comment: OK, first of all, you don't need to `cat` file into awk via pipe. `awk` can take command-line arguments just fine, and you don't need  to declare space as separator for awk in your second command. In fact, the 3 parts are condenced into just one nice command like this: `awk -F'[>|]' '{print substr($2,2)}' input.txt`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks. I don't have throughly knowledge of it. By giving an answer, i'm also learning. I tried to find about `'{print substr($2,2)}'` but i could not that's why i had to use `cat` and second command of `awk`.

Comment: @daisy It's great that you're learning and trying to answer. I've been there, started out just like you. This basically uses > and | as separators, and thus makes our desired words the second "column" in the input file. That also means that the column will have leading space character, so we print the substring of that column, starting at index 2 of the whole column. Keep on learning, and feel free to edit your answer to incorporate this suggestion. I've nothing against that

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl

Here's a perl one-liner that does the job:

```
$ perl -ne 's/^.*[|>]\ //;print' inp.txt                                                
Aminobenzoate 
Atrazine 
Bacterial 
Benzoate 
beta-Lactam 
Biosynthesis 
Caprolactam 
Carbapenem
```

Or even shorter as suggested by [Matija Nalis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914364/how-do-i-grep-the-text-after-two-special-characters#comment1440311_914375) in the comments

```
perl -pe 's/^.*[|>]\ //' inp.txt
```

It basically takes and deletes everything from beginning of the string till either `|` or `>`, and then prints stuff.

---

#### Alternative sed with grouping

If you haven't noticed yet, all answers here operate on the idea of *deleting* the leading information. What we also can do, is *group* what we want and replace whole line with that. The focus this is not on the leading information, but on the stuff that we actually want in the output.

Take for instance this `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^.*[>|] \(.*$\)/\1/' inp.txt                                                     
Aminobenzoate 
Atrazine 
Bacterial 
Benzoate 
beta-Lactam 
Biosynthesis 
Caprolactam 
Carbapenem
```

What happens is that whatever is inside `\(` and `\)` will get treated as one whole things, and referenced via `\1`. This command basically says "take whatever comes after `>` or `|`   plus a space and make it as one group, and replace that whole line with what we put into that `\1` group.

---

#### Python

While python scripts can be a little lengthier, they are typically more readable and explicit. Here's what we could do with Python 3 script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import re
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        print(re.split("<|>|\|",line.strip())[1].strip())
```

The key ideas here are the following:

- we open whatever file is provides as command-line argument
- we iterate over each line of the file
- using `re.split()` function, we split each line into list using `>` or `|` or `>` as separator.
- Then we extract the second (index `[1]` in the list, because lists start at 0's index) item in that list, and using `strip()` function remove leading and trailing whitespace.
- All of those actions of `re.split()` and list extraction occur within `print()` function, so once all of those operations are done, we get the desired output string, and move on to process next line

If we wanted to,  we could always shove everything into a one-liner like so:

```
$ python -c 'import re,sys;print("\n".join([ re.split("<|>|\|",l.strip())[1].strip() for l in sys.stdin]))' < inp.txt    
Aminobenzoate
Atrazine
Bacterial
Benzoate
beta-Lactam
Biosynthesis
Caprolactam
Carbapenem
```

---

#### Other side notes:

- if this is really a `diff` output as [Ravexina's answer suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/914419/295286) we can always include `<` into all expressions presented here by adding `<` into square brackets. Thus we'll have:

  - `perl -pe 's/^.*[|><]\ //;' inp.txt`
  - `sed 's/^.*[><|] \(.*$\)/\1/' inp.txt`
  - Python solution was written after this became a consideration, so that solution already includes `<`

Comment: BTW, `perl -ne` with `print` at the end is better written just as `perl -pe` (without `print` at the end). Also, there is extra (unneeded) '$' in your sed example

Comment: @MatijaNalis  Thanks for the suggestions. Included those already

Answer (score 3):

First of all I believe that this is a `diff -y` output, so you may also include `<` too.

We can only use grep to do this via look behind:

```
grep -Po "(?<=(\||<|>)\s).*" file.txt
```

- `.*` Look for anything any times repeated.
- `(?<=(\||<|>)\s)`, which is behind of one of these ( `|` or `<` or `>` ) followed by an space.

a more clear version is:

```
grep -Po '(?<=[<|>]\s).*' file.txt
```

---

Or using `grep` and `cut` as you were trying:

```
grep -Eo "(<|>|\|).*" file.txt | cut -f2 -d' '
```

- `-E`: extended `grep`
- `-o` Print only the matched part
- `(<|>|\|)` means `<` or `|` or `>`.
- `.*` every thing & any times repeated

Which brigs us to this point:

```
enter code here
> Aminobenzoate 
| Atrazine 
| Bacterial 
| Benzoate 
| beta-Lactam 
> Biosynthesis 
| Caprolactam 
| Carbapenem
```

then using `cut` we get the second field which is our strings, which is:

```
Aminobenzoate
Atrazine
Bacterial
Benzoate
beta-Lactam
Biosynthesis
Caprolactam
Carbapenem
```

Comment: How about  `grep -Po '[<|>]\s*\K.*'`? no need for `cut`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, I add a solution with "look behind" too ;) however yours is more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

The least amount of modification from your current command would be to replace your mention to the literal `|` character in your regex to a reference to a character class containing both `|` and `>`, `[|>]`, which will match either of them :

```
grep -o '  [|>].*$'| cut -c5-
```

Others have explored `awk`, `sed` and `perl` implementations, but your `grep` implementation could also be improved further.

For example, you could get rid of the `cut` command in the following ways :

- by using Perl's `\K` flag : `grep -Po '[>|]\s*\K.*`
- by using PCRE's lookbehind : `grep -Po '(?<=[|>]\s).*'` note that this will only work with a fixed amount of spaces between the delimiter and the target word, as PCRE engines aren't required to implement variable-width lookbehind and generally don't.

Comment: Thankyou so much all of u  for your help the query is solved.